# Filter a list and order items by relevance

Tags: python, search, filtering

I have a list of strings:

```
my_list = ['Paul', 'Robinson', 'Hismith', 'Smith']
```

I need to filter it and order the results by relevance:

```
> filter_list(my_list, 'smith')
> ['Smith', 'Hismith']
> 
> filter_list(my_list, 'paul')
> ['Paul']
```

My list is small and it would be nice if I could use as less logic/libraries as possible.

How would you do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I only need simple relevance logic so that the ordered list can be used in a more useful way by the user. Full matches appearing first is the most important bit (and probably the only one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult to tell, what is the "relevance". In my answer I accept only if the sought `word` is within the element and sort the results by their length (good chances that 100% matches will appear first):

```
def filter_list(li, word):
    return sorted((elem for elem in li if word.lower() in elem.lower()), key=len)
```

Comment: +1 even though this doesn't sort by "relevance", whatever Marco meant by that.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I have added some "relevance" feature.

Comment: This was exactly my implementation but without the relevance part.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like the following (you may want to tweak the `cutoff=` option though):

```
import difflib

my_list = ['Paul', 'Robinson', 'Hismith', 'Smith']
print difflib.get_close_matches('Paul', my_list)
# ['Paul']
print difflib.get_close_matches('Smith', my_list)
# ['Hismith', 'Smith']
```

Comment: Great answer (although without the relevance bit).

Comment: @MarcoFucci The definition of "relevance" wasn't defined at the point of my answer, so I took a punt on "most relevant" == "most similar"